# Ubuntu won't boot due to missing Bootmgr

Tags: installation

I had Windows 7 and had to recover to factory settings.  I had no Windows 7 disk, so I decided to switch to Ubuntu.  I formated my c:drive but when I go to install Ubuntu, it tells me that it is missing the Bootmgr.  I formated my disk the installation disk to fat32.  I'm still getting the message bootmgr missing.  What can I do?

Comment: this sounds like you are not booting to the cd. You may need to adjust bios settings to boot the cd first

Answer (score 0):

You can download the bootable CD of [Gparted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/download.php), and delete all partitions, and then start the Ubuntu installation from CD.

Or if you feel comfortable, boot from the Ubuntu CD, and when you get to the Installation Type screen, choose Something Else,

[image]

delete the partitions, and create new ones for Ubuntu.  You need to create at least two partitions, a Primary Ext4 with mount point as `/`, and a swap partition.

[image]

[image]

**Note:** The image above are for instructional purposes, your real life situation maybe different.